# Is a dictionary with a single pair of values overkill?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I want to return an int and a string from a record selected on a form to the invoker of the form.

I could create a class with those two members and pass an instance of that back. Or I could use a Dictionary with just one pair of values (one key, one corresponding value), which seems to be the easiest way to proceed.

I want to assign whatever it is I return to the DataBindings property of a Listview.

Are there any reasons for not using a Dictionary<> for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using `Tuple<int, string>` or `KeyValuePair<int, string>`? Or just use an anonymous type?

```
return new { Foo = "foo", Bar = "bar" };
```

That way (assuming binding works with anonymous types) you could give the properties meaningful names...

Answer (score 0):

The Dictionary route will give you room to expand in the future and so, it is the best route.
And I don't think you should concern with speed, in this specific regard, because it's not noticeable.
You can also initialize it with your own capacity, in this case 1 but who knows in the future what will it be:

> `Dictionary<keyType, valueType> dct = new Dictionary<keyType, valueType>(1)`

It's better to use .net structures where you can. It is also more efficient then anonymous types.

Comment: Do not add unnecessary features; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it

Comment: Dour, the dictionary is _already being used_. So this is the right path. It's not implemented just in case it's implemented to be used right now.

Comment: No, a dictionary is not already being used; read the question. And a Dictionary is unnecessary to solve the problem so it *should* not be used. You do not know what the asker will be doing in the future.

Comment: He has a choice between a dictionary and something else. If he chooses the dictionary he _will use it_. You misinterpret the context of YAGNI. It's the "same" effort to implement with a dictionary or a class but if you have the choice you should use what it's easier to extend and manage (OOP principle). So, in this case to choose a dictionary is _better and it will be used_. If he were to implement some other thing, just in case, but he wouldn't know when he will use, this would break YAGNI. Do you understand now ?